# free online password manager

Tags: gratis, web-apps, hosted, password-manager

I'm searching for a free online password manager that I can access from anywhere, that gives me some peace of mind, is trustable, and easy to use.

I read about LastPass [in PCMag](https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2426798,00.asp), but wanted to ask the community about your opinions and suggestions.

What Password Manager would you recommend?

Comment: Asking if something is the best, or asking for favorites, isn’t on-topic here. You should describe your requirements (how you want to use it, what features it needs to have) and then people can recommend something (maybe LastPass, maybe something else).

Comment: I fully agree with @unor here, and hence have adjusted your post accordingly (so it won't be closed). As for the topic: "online password manager" IMHO contradicts "peace of mind" (and often also "trustable"): you can never be sure if someone has hacked it. So if you ask me: my favorite password manager should run locally, have no access to the network and store its content well encrypted. Needless to say: the one I use does :)

Comment: If you need it just for websites, you can try to use Google Chrome with a google accout to store them.

Answer (score 2):

thanks for your comments.

I finally opted for [KeePass](https://keepass.info/index.html) following @Izzy's recommendation (offline password manager).

LastPass (and any online solution) it's riskier and you have to trust them and their system.

Comment: But in the same way you have to trust that the KeePass binary you downloaded has not been tampered with... Trust is far from an easy topic...

Comment: LastPass is used by many organisations, who trust it to keep passwords not only for employees, but for system accounts as well

Comment: I heard a news where some malware browser plugins were able to read KeePass files from browser cache and unlock them. Moreover, as much I heard about LastPass, your data is encrypted by your master password / key. So it is safe to use. It also gives you the flexibility to fill password automatically across the devices and browsers.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend 2 possible solutions for you, and their both open source:

1. I have prepared a small list of my own password management setup which uses KeePass like you have mentioned you chose, however it uses KeePassXC along with other applications to complement the ecosystem of devices I use. I think KeePassXC is somewhat better than KeePass. Check the link below.
2. Second option would be to use Bitwarden. I used it for a while and it was excellent. You can store your database in your own server, use it free, check the source code and if you like it a lot, there is even a paid option with additional features.

I hope this helped you to find a perfect solution for your needs.

Links:

https://alternativeto.net/list/3139/password-management-setup

https://bitwarden.com/